# Get just the filename from a file path stored as a string

Tags: python, path

How can I remove the path and leave only the filename and extension inside a variable?

```
root=tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
FileName=filedialog.askopenfilenames()
print(Filename)
```

I want only for example `namefile.txt` and not the whole path, like `/path/to/namefile.txt`.

Comment: Have a look at `os.path.basename()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For python3.4+, [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```py
from pathlib import Path

name = Path(Filename).name
```

Comment: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Comment: @andreealombardo in your code, you use `askopenfilenames()`, which returns a tuple. Try `Path(Filename[0]).name`

Comment: It's worth pointing out, I think, that this works on any platform. Pretty much any method other than this requires manually mucking about with different path separators on Windows vs. Mac/Linux, and ain't nobody got time for that.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to sanitize the string so it works cross-platform, then you can just pull the last section.

```
filename = filename.replace('\\', '/') # Turns the Windows filepath format to the Literally everything else format.
filename = filename.split('/')[-1]
```